# CoreData relationship Fault throws unimplemented SQL generation for predicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using CoreData with MagicalRecord for store management in my app. I made the xcdatamodel and generated the NSManagedObjects subclasses. My problem is that when I try to use one of the generated accessors for a relationship I get an 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate' error. This is happening only with one of the generated accessors.

To be more specific, here's the code for the classes I'm using. The problem I have is in the Crop -> Row relationship, which is many to many:

```
extension Crop {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Crop> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Crop>(entityName: "Crop");
}

@NSManaged public var phLevels: Int16
@NSManaged public var row: NSSet?
@NSManaged public var states: NSSet?
```

// MARK: Generated accessors for row:

```
extension Crop {

@objc(addRowObject:)
@NSManaged public func addToRow(_ value: Row)

@objc(removeRowObject:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromRow(_ value: Row)

@objc(addRow:)
@NSManaged public func addToRow(_ values: NSSet)

@objc(removeRow:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromRow(_ values: NSSet)
```

Here's the Row:

```
extension Row {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Row> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Row>(entityName: "Row");
}

@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var crops: NSSet?
@NSManaged public var paddock: Paddock?
```

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for crops
extension Row {

```
@objc(addCropsObject:)
@NSManaged public func addToCrops(_ value: Crop)

@objc(removeCropsObject:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromCrops(_ value: Crop)

@objc(addCrops:)
@NSManaged public func addToCrops(_ values: NSSet)

@objc(removeCrops:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromCrops(_ values: NSSet)
```

I'm trying to add a Row to the Crop:

```
plantingCrop?.addToRow(row)
```

And there's when I get the

> unimplemented SQL generation for predicate

Or if i try the other way around the same result:

```
row.addToCrops(plantingCrop!)
```

I'm a bit lost here, plantingCrop is generated ok, i use other accessors before I set the row in the crop and they are working ok (they are one-to-many relationships), I tried to regenerate the subclasses and the same result. In the debugger I can see at that point that the relationship is faulting when I try to use it. There's probably something wrong that I'm missing but i cannot find it!

**UPDATE**

Tried with the code below and the same result.

`if let rowsFromCrop = plantingCrop?.mutableSetValue(forKey: "row") {
        rowsFromCrop.add(row)
 }`

**EDIT**

From Apple Docs, the tick on the transient property means that the attribute is a property that you define as part of the model, but which is not saved to the persistent store as part of an entity instance’s data. Core Data does track changes you make to transient properties, so they are recorded for undo operations. Then says:

"If you undo a change to a transient property that uses nonmodeled information, Core Data does not invoke your set accessor with the old value — it simply updates the snapshot information."

I don't quite completely understand this last line, but it might be that because it was a transient property CD wasn't invoking the right accessor?

Comment: Well, I did solve this by removing the thick on the transient property of the relationship,  but I'm still not sure why this solution worked, if someone can explain to me would be helpful!

Comment: Maybe if you explain what "the thick on the transient property" means first. :)

Comment: I've added more information about the transient properties on Core Data @TomHarrington. Cheers!